# JOptionPane predefined selections from linked list

Tags: java, swing, linked-list, joptionpane

I am currently working on a project in which I have to input validate a users answer from a linked list. In the list there are between 6 and 8 possible answers. I was looking at using JOptionPane with a predefined selection, but I'm not too sure how to do this from a linked list, if I even can?

I am looking for some help as to how I would do this, or even some other suggestions on something I could do? The key thing is I need to be able to validate the users input, which is why I was looking at doing it from the predefined selection.

This was the kind of thing I was looking at 
http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/UsingJOptionPanewithapredefinedselections.htm

As I say I am open to any other suggestions as to how I would be able to do this so any suggestions are welcome.

:)

Answer (score 2):

The example you posted seems to be perfectly ok. However, it does not explain anything.

First, the core method is

```
public static Object showInputDialog(Component parentComponent,
                                 Object message,
                                 String title,
                                 int messageType,
                                 Icon icon,
                                 Object[] selectionValues,
                                 Object initialSelectionValue)
                             throws HeadlessException
```

You can read the API [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog-java.awt.Component-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-int-javax.swing.Icon-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.Object-).

So, what you basically want to fill in here is `message`, `title`, `messageType`, `selectionValues` and maybe `initialSelectionValue`.

Firstly `message` and `title` do pretty much explain itself, so I won't bother with these.

The `messageType` parameter denotes the style how the message will appear to the user. For example, if you use `JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE` here, the message will appear thus the system will probably play an error beep.

The possible options are all contained as constants in `JOptionPane`.

- ERROR_MESSAGE
- INFORMATION_MESSAGE
- WARNING_MESSAGE
- QUESTION_MESSAGE
- PLAIN_MESSAGE

Now, the crucial parameter is `selectionValues` which is of type `Object[]`. The API says it's 'an array of Objects that gives the possible selections', so basically exactly what you're currently having in your list. You only have to convert it to an `Array` (in the example below I use a temporary copy, which is perfectly ok with 6-8 values).

Last but not least, the `initialSelectionValue` lets you specify which value shall be selected initially.

Hence, all you want to do is something like

```
public Foo select(List<Foo> options, String message, String title, Foo initiallySelected) {
    return (Foo)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
        null, // we don't have a parent component in this example
        message, // the message that will appear above the selection
        title, // the title that will appear in the window's caption
        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, // style is question
        null, // we don't show an Icon here, it's just a gimmick
        list.toArray(), // the values which can be selected from
        initiallySelected // the initially selected value
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback :)